# Modal window close on clicking outside

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript, so I need an explanation of how the code is working. In w2Schools there is a modal window code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp, in which there is a function -

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

How is it working? function(event) defines where event happens,click event happens on window, so why event.target is being checked whether the event happens on modal?  I mean why are we not checking if `event.target` is if outside modal or `if(event.target!==modal)`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use dev tools all the time when you are stuck. That's how I improved myself on html elements when I was a beginner in that too. I'll make it clear for you with the help of pictures.

[image]
As we already know what modal is by `var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");` we need to click div with id myModal. And thats the one picture.[image]

To make it even more clear for you, I've clicked `background-color` property to make see where exactly is `#myModal`. As you can see here, whenever user clicks on this black space. The modal will be closed.